# Memoizing @property values in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have properties in a class that I want to calculate lazily at runtime. However, once they've been calculated they won't change. Is there syntactic sugar for memoizing values? Right now I have code like this all over the place:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *bedroomsString;

...

- (NSString *)bedroomsString
{
    if (_bedroomsString == nil) {
        _bedroomsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@bd", _bedrooms];
    }
    return _bedroomsString;
}
```

I'd like to just do something like

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, memoize) NSString *bedroomsString;

....

- (NSString *)bedroomsString
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@bd", _bedrooms];
}
```

Anyone know of such a thing?

Comment: Is there a setter for this property?

Comment: For something that simple there's no real advantage in lazy init vs just calculating the string each time.  Or you could set the string in the setter for the _bedrooms variable.

Comment: While there are cases were memoizing is useful, the example you give is a great example of why you must be so careful with it and should use it sparingly (i.e. be slow to adopt shortcuts for it). If `_bedrooms` changes, you're now stuck and you'll get inconsistent results. In your preferred solution, it's spooky action at a distance, because the annotation is a long way from the method. I've found that the cases where this is really useful are actually much rarer than people think given the subtle bugs it can cause. For those rare cases, the couple of lines of code are not a problem.

Comment: I guess the real question is, what performance problem did you encounter that you decided that spending memory on ivars was worth it "all over the place?" (Again, not saying that there are not reasons to memoize occasionally, but usually hooking the setter is the better answer.)

Comment: Thanks but I'm not wondering when to use memoization or precomputation, I just wanted to know if there was a cleaner way to memoize in Objective-C.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a single liner you can do something like

```
- (NSString *)bedroomsString
{
  return _bedroomsString ?: (_bedroomsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@bd", _bedrooms]);
}
```

or if one line gets a bit too unwieldy then you can use

```
- (NSString *)bedroomsString
{
  return _bedroomsString ?: ({
    _bedroomsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@bd", _bedrooms]
  });
}
```

Both of these are covered in this article on [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/new-years-2014/)

Comment: A default value seems to be more of what the OP wants, but I'll keep my answer up for people trying to memoize. +1.

Comment: I'm not sure of your distinction between memoize and default value here. In both cases above the computed value is being stored into the ivar so it is not calculated the second time.

Comment: Sorry, I am so used to thinking of tables and functions when it comes to memoizing that I overlooked the fact that 1 value not being recomputed is also memoization.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use [this helper](https://gist.github.com/mikelikespie/899774).

For example:

```
- (NSString *)bedroomsString
{
    return _MEMO(bedroomsString, ^{
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@bd", _bedrooms];
    })();
}
```

Doesn't really help so much with your relatively small example but, if the example was bigger, this might help.